# How can I trace where logs are being created in AWS after performing some action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

AWS logging is very versatile, for almost any operation done there are logs created. 
A problem I encounter is that although these logs are created, sometimes they are created in places I'm not aware of. Is there a way (for example some voodoo api call) that given an api action, retrieves all the logs or all the locations where logs have gone to in the cloud?

For example, if I have bucket notifications active on a bucket then if I put an object in the bucket I want to know that:

- Access log is created in X
- Access log is created in Y
- Putting object is monitored in server Z logs
- Notifications are sent to this and that SQS
- etc...

Comment: I don't think there is one place or an API call that can be used to get all the logs-related info. That's the reason I guess few companies have created solutions out of it. Data Dog etc provides AWS integration so that you can view all the logs on a single dashboard. There are/should be many open source solution as well.

Comment: Datadog can be useful, but it is a giant platform with a learning curve to set up with minimal customer support available and can be quite expensive if you're not careful (lots of hidden fees on the AWS side from data transfer of your log files).  For most things, you can mitigate this somewhat by setting up your projects using cloudformation templates and setting the names of where the logs go in the templates, so at least you have control of what their names are and can know and see all resources in a cloudformation set [not including audit logs, like those created by CloudTrail, of course]